# promises with search function

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an array of objects, there is a function to search for a book by name, I want to use the search function through promises, after a successful search, the convert function should be executed. when I do this, I get an empty array

```
let book1 = {
  name: "wind",
  author: 'smith',
  size: 314,
};
let book2 = {
  name: "moon",
  author: 'wild',
  size: 421,
};
let book3 = {
  name: "sun",
  author: 'jacob',
  size: 510,
};
let books1 = [book1, book2, book3];
let books = [];

function searchName(search) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    books1 = books1.filter(function(elem) {
      elem.name.includes(search)
    })
  })
};

function convert() {
  return books = books1.map(item => item.name);
};
searchName("wind").then(convert);
console.log(books);
```

Comment: Your promise never resolves or rejects. Also it's doing something synchronous, so making it a promise isn't giving any value.

Comment: There's no point to wrapping a synchronous process in a promise (99.9999% of the time, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

1. Add **return** statement in **book1.filter** to get filtered array
2. Call **resolve** callback in **Promise** body
3. If you do not catch rejected **Promise** you can omit **reject** callback in **Promise executor's** arguments
4. **console.log(books)** at the end of your example will always return an empty array because **Promise** will be executed after the **console.log**. Read about **Microtasks**, here is a good explanation https://javascript.info/microtask-queue

Try this code:

```
    function searchName(search) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        books1 = books1.filter(function (elem) {
          return elem.name.includes(search);
        });

        if (books1.length) {
          resolve();
        }
      });
    }

    function convert() {
      books = books1.map(item => item.name);

      console.log(books);

      return books;
    }

    searchName('wind').then(convert);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Promises incorrectly in a variety of ways -

```js
const books =         // use const for bindings that will not be reassigned
  [ { name: "wind"    // objects can be declared in an array, if you wish
    , author: 'smith' // <-- book1
    , size: 314,
    }
  , { name: "moon"    // <-- book2
    , author: 'wild'
    , size: 421
    }
  , { name: "sun"     // <-- book3
    , author: 'jacob'
    , size: 510
    }
  ]
  
const searchBooks = (query = "") =>
  new Promise((resolve, _) =>    // <-- reject unused
    resolve(books.filter(b =>    // call resolve, don't reassign books
      b.name.includes(query)
    ))
  )

const convert = (books = []) =>  // receives argument
  books.map(b => b.name)         // return a value, don't use reassignment

const input =
  document.querySelector("input")
  
input.addEventListener
  ( "keyup"
  , e =>
      searchBooks(e.target.value) // gets filtered books
        .then(convert)            // passes books to convert, gets result
        .then(console.log, console.error) // then log the result, or error
  )
```

```html
<input placeholder="search here..."/>
```

These are all common mistakes beginners make when first using Promises. I think this related [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) will be very helpful to you.

---

In this example, we wrap a Promise around `filter` but it is purely synchronous and actually unnecessary -

```js
const searchBooks = (query = "") =>
  books.filter(b =>    
    b.name.includes(query)
  )
```

In a real scenario, maybe the data is coming from over the network. Then we'd have use for Promises -

```js
const fetchJson = (url = "") =>
  fetch(url).then(res => res.json())

const searchBooks = (query = "") =>
  fetchJson("./path/to/books.json") // fetch the books data
    .then(books =>                  // then using the books
      books.filter(b =>             // filter the books
        b.name.includes(query)
      )
    )                               // .then returns another promise
```

---

Related, `async`/`await` make it easy to write asynchronous code that appears more like synchronous code. Using `async` our function will automatically return a Promise, and it allows us to `await` any expression inside the function's body -

```
const fetchJson = (url = "") =>
  fetch(url).then(res => res.json())

const searchBooks = async (query = "") => // <-- async keyword
{ const books =     
    await fetchJson("./path/to/books.json") // <-- await keyword

  return books.filter(b => 
    b.name.includes(query)
  )
}
```